# Distance between graph labels on a time/date axis

Tags: javascript, datetime, d3.js, time-series

For a time/date axis I want to find out the distance between the graph labels

For example lets say that we have a plot of 1 hour from 14:00 -> 15:00 I want to display a label every 10 minutes so the distance between each graph label is 10 minutes

But if you zoom in then you would have a plot of 20 seconds and then I want to display a label every 2 second

In the end I would also like to support weeks,months

Is there a generic way to calculate this?

I tried the following :

1. Find out the number of seconds between range a,b
2. set a hardcoded distance

The issue with this is that in the end I will end up with a bunch of if statements and I am not even using the zoom level in my calculation